# selecting from one mysql table (friends) and ordering the results by fields in another table (users)?

Tags: mysql

How would I go about selecting from one mysql table (friends) and ordering the results by fields in another table (users)?

The tables are setup as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(2),
  `mutual` int(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

basically what I need to do is pull in the user_ids from the friends table, match them to the users table and get the users data, then order the output by the following:

```
concat(users.first_name, users.last_name) ASC, friends.mutual DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a `JOIN` to achieve this.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM friends 
    JOIN users ON friends.user_id = users.id 
    ORDER BY concat(users.first_name, users.last_name) ASC, friends.mutual DESC
```

Comment: Hi Chetan, I assumed that was the case, but alas, that is one of my weak areas, can you offer a bit more detail to guide for my particular case?

Comment: @Jaime: By the way, the question isn't clear as to whether you want to select data from the users table and order by the friends table, or select data from the friends table and order by the users table. My answer attends to the latter. If you wanted the former, just make it `SELECT * FROM users JOIN friends ...`

Comment: Chetan, I modified what you posted first and it works well, thank you very much.  I was needing to select the users data to display.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one! I think it should work!

```
SELECT
friends.user_id, users.*
FROM
friends, users
WHERE
  friends.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY
  concat(users.first_name, users.last_name) ASC, friends.mutual DESC
```

Comment: Im going to regret this, but pride goes before the fall: What do u mean with ANSI-89 syntax? That I didnt made the JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

Select users.first_name, users.last_name, friends.mutual
from users, friends
where users.id = friends.id AND friends.mutual != 0;

May work, or you may need to tune it. I do not have env to give you exact query :)

Happy Mysqling :)

--Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN friends ON users.id=friends.user_id
ORDER BY CONCAT(users.first_name, users.last_name) ASC, friends.mutual DESC
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
select concat(users.first_name,users.last_name) as name,friends.mutual as friends from users 
right join friends on friends.users_id = users.id order by name asc, friends desc
```

This should do the job.